# JPA entity composite index collection

Tags: hibernate, list, jpa, entity, composite-key

I am using JPA + hibernate in my project. I have to retrieve data from an already existing database, and cannot make modifications on it.

The schema is like, there are multiple organizations, each company has many bills and each bill has many lineitems.

```
organization 
{

 id;

 name;

 ...
 }

bill 
{

   id;

   organization o;

   amount;

   ....

   (EAGER, mappedBy=bill)
   List<Lineitem> lineitems;
}


lineitem
{
     id;

     organization o;

     (EAGER)
     bill b;


     itemCode

     .....
}
```

The indexes in the database schema (currently present)
bill table
--> orgId (non unique index)

lineitem table
--> orgId, billId

When a bill is being requested, it is doing this first

```
Select *
from bills
where id = ?
```

which is fine, since its a fetch on primary key. Now it fetches the lineitems

it is doing

`select *
from lineitems
where billId = ?`

There is no index at the database level on billId. There is a non unique composite index on orgId,billId.

What do i have to put so that hibernate fetches lineitems using orgId along with the billId ..  as..

`select *
from lineitems
where billId = ? and orgId = ?`

I did not know what would be a suitable title.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by removing the `mappedBy=bill` in the bill entity (for lineitems list) and then using `@joincolumns` to use both org_id and bill_id for the join